# mysql temporary table in subquery

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery, temp-tables

I'm trying to use temp table in subquery (stored procedure), but it returns empty result set...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_profile_with_templates`(IN _username NVARCHAR(50), IN _template NVARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO @template FROM profile_template WHERE name=_template LIMIT 1;
    SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=_username AND template=@template LIMIT 1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sections SELECT * FROM profile_template_section WHERE template=@template;
    **CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS components SELECT * FROM component_template WHERE section IN (SELECT id FROM sections);**
    SELECT * FROM sections;
    SELECT * FROM components;
    SELECT * FROM component_template_option WHERE component_template IN (SELECT id FROM components);
END
```

the query between the **'s is the one returns empty... 
if I run the same query on the real table, It returns values...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_profile_with_templates`(IN _username NVARCHAR(50), IN _template NVARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS sections;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS components;
    SELECT id INTO @template FROM profile_template WHERE name=_template LIMIT 1;
    SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=_username AND template=@template LIMIT 1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sections SELECT * FROM profile_template_section WHERE template=@template;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS components SELECT * FROM component_template WHERE section IN (SELECT id FROM sections);
    SELECT * FROM sections;
    SELECT * FROM components;
    SELECT * FROM component_template_option WHERE component_template IN (SELECT id FROM components);
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS sections;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS components;
END
```

Comment: Are you making sure the temporary tables are dropped between executions on the same connection? `CREATE...IF NOT IS EXISTS..SELECT` will not insert into the table if it already exists.

Comment: so should I add drop table in the end of the procedure?

Comment: Adding `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;` queries to the start and end of the procedure for each temporary table created by the procedure usually keeps things going smoothly. _(Technically only needed once, but if something goes wrong in a call they could get stuck if you only have the drops at the end; and if they're only at beginning, they would be left hanging around around after the call.)_

Comment: Okay, now it works, but when I receive the data with node js and changing the parameters, the data stays the same (which sounds like the table is not dropped)...

Comment: You have multiple selects (without into's), which will cause the procedure to return multiple result sets (looks like four); are you handling those appropriately? Also, don't lean too heavily on @ variables; they are not private and can carry over values from previous executions.

Comment: It's like that in the mysql console too.. it might be the variable, you're right... how do I drop this variable too?

Comment: DECLARE one in the procedure instead.

Comment: Thank's!! you solved it :) how can I vote for your answer? I can't find the vote button...

Comment: I'll put an actual answer, these have just been comments.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote apparently, I hope someone else will vote for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `CREATE ... SELECT` statements, the SELECT portion will not populate the table if it already exists.

If creating temporary tables in a stored procedure that will not be used outside of the procedure, it is best to use `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS` statements at the start and end of the procedure. The ending ones are so the procedure cleans up after itself; the starting ones ensure temporary tables left over from previous executions (that errored/failed before dropping them) do not interfere with current executions. *You could also wrap the main body of the procedure in a TRY, and have the drops outside of the TRY, to ensure the drops occur, but that is a bit more advanced.*

When using session/user/@ variables, keep in mind they are global for the database connection and can carry over values; when possible use locally DECLAREd variables (whose scope does not go beyond the procedure). *Bonus: Also, try to make sure the names of such variables, and procedure parameters, are not ambiguous with field names of the tables used in the procedure; it can cause very hard to diagnose issues.*